# Reference Classes and Normal Classes in C++/CX

Tags: c++-cx

What is the difference between **ref class Hello** and normal class like **class hello** in C++/CX. Till now I studied about normal classes and Reference objects but this reference classes is something which I found**strong text** as new and Interesting.

Its deceleration is like this

```
 ref class A: public InterfaceA
 {
   //Implementing Interface
  }
```

Comment: I'm not too sure the `c++` tag is relevant considering C++ has neither `ref class`, nor `public class`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699870.aspx

Comment: That's C++/CX, which isn't even the C++/CLI you originally tagged this with. Neither of those are C++.

Comment: yeah you are right, So I changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref classes are the only types of classes exposed when creating WinRT components. More information here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699870.aspx